# Server Side HTTP 303 redirect not persisting request header (Safari + IE)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, http, safari, http-redirect

My webapp is making a ajax HTTP request to my server with a GET request, which will respond with 303 status code. (I believe) the browser handles this redirect and makes a GET request following Location header from previous 303 response. Only problem is that my initial response (resulted in 303) had a request header, Authentication. On Safari and IE, this header is not forwarded to the redirect GET request  (Chrome and Firefox has no problem). This header is very important, without it, my GET request results in 401 Unauthorized.

I'm very naive with the underlying structure browser behaviour, I'm confused with the following things:

1. Is it really the browser handling the 303 HTTP redirect?
2. How does Firefox and Chrome foward or persist request header for redirect request?
3. Should I expect Safari and IE be able to forward my request header on the redirect, like Chrome and Firefox do?
4. Is there anywhere, on the client side, I can interfere with the redirect request - so I can set the request header?

### My initial HTTP request

**Request** URL: DOMAIN/integrator/profiles/campus/default
**Request Headers**

```
Authorization:Bearer f85a5ce3-7c08-4e4d-a1b3
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json
Referer:http://localhost:3007/html5storefront/
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

**Status Code**:303 See Other
**Response Headers**

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Mon, 03 Mar 2014 21:38:13 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Location:http://localhost:3007/integrator/profiles/campus/gi4dgqzsgrbuelkegmydoljug4ztgl
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

**Request URL:** DOMAIN/integrator/profiles/campus/gi4dgqzsgrbuelkegmydoljug4ztgl
**Redirect request by Chrome** (similar on Firefox)

```
Authorization:Bearer f85a5ce3-7c08-4e4d-a1b3
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json
Referer:http://localhost:3007/html5storefront/
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

**Request URL:** DOMAIN/integrator/profiles/campus/gi4dgqzsgrbuelkegmydoljug4ztgl
**Redirect request by Safari** (similar on IE)

```
Referer:http://localhost:3007/html5storefront/
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Please note the abscence of Authorization header on the redirected request by Safari.

Thank you all for reading my question.

Comment: The problem solved is on server side.

Comment: So what was the server side solution? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: @Hullah on the server side, when redirect on 307, our server attached the authorization token as part of the requesting url. e.g. request <domain>/profile/default, server will respond 307 (see other), which redirect with new request <domain>/profile/<id>?auth=xxxxauthtoken